# Array elements of a vector are not filled in ParallelTable environment

Tags: parallelization

If I use the following code the `Array` `arr` still contains zeros.

```
arr= Array[0 &, 10];

ParallelTable[

  arr[[i]] = 1,

  {i, 1, 10}

  ];

arr
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

What is here the problem?

I know I can use:

```
arr= Array[1 &, 10];
```

But in my case I have a complex calculation which's results should be saved inside of `ParallelTable` environment into an array.

I am programming with Mathematica 10.3.1.0 on Windows 10 Professional 64 Bit and have an i7-4940-MX 3,1 GHz processor (4 cores).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set `arr` as a shared variable first, using [`SetSharedVariable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetSharedVariable.html),

```
SetSharedVariable[arr];
arr = Array[0 &, 10];
ParallelTable[Set[arr[[i]], 1], {i, 1, 10}];
arr
(* {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} *)
```

Comment: I have asked two other questions about problems with `ParallelTable` and it might be that you could solve them: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104328/mysterious-behaviour-of-paralleltable and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104310/export-bug-in-combination-with-paralleltable. It could be that both have to do with `SetSharedVariable`