# How to determine side-effects in parallel computation? Possibly associated to Kernel not closing reliably

Tags: parallelization, debugging, side-effect

I have written a bunch of code to simulate some measurements. To speed things up, I intended to obtain the measurement values via a `ParallelTable`. However, it turns out that there seem to be side-effects which cause the results from `ParallelTable` to be occasionally wrong (the `Table` equivalent produces reasonable results).

Since the code is pretty long with many functions that are temporarily needed, I would like to sketch the general scheme and ask for a way how to debug such issues. It appears to me that this has not been covered in a (somehow) general way, although I find it very relevant.

The system that is being measured is set up in a matrix `system[var1_,var2_,...]:=system[var1,var2,...]=...` which depends on some global variables that are totally constant throughout all computation and really no longer touched after initialization. Basically, the time-dependence of `system` is given by a scalar function `f[var1_,var2_,...]:=f[var1,var2,...]=...` that takes the same arguments as `system`. In a nutshell, I have a function that solves a system of coupled ODEs that depend on `system` and measures some quantity (e.g. take the trace `Tr`) of the particular solution after a certain time. The process of evolving the system and measuring is wrapped up in a function `measure[var1_,var2_,...]:=Module[...]` that essentially also depends on the same variables as `system`.

Now, evaluating

```
result1=ParallelTable[measure[var1,var2],{var1,v1min,v1max},{var2,v2min,v2max}];
result2=Table[measure[var1,var2],{var1,v1min,v1max},{var2,v2min,v2max}];
```

gives moreorless the same results - with exceptions for some values of `var1,var2`. Evaluating the `ParallelTable` with same parameters a couple of times reveals that these exceptions "change position" (with respect to `var1,var2`) so that I conclude it must be side-effects.
However, since I do not touch any global variables and all local variables are defined within `Module` or `Block` (it doesn't matter which one I pick), I do have no clue where the side-effects originate from.

I thought that memoization of `system` and `f` might be an issue, but since they are never called twice with the same set of `var1,var2` during a `(Parallel)Table` it appears to me that this should also not be an issue.

Because this is a problem that may often appear in general, I would like to know if

1. someone can spot a possible origin of side-effects in my brief sketch of the code above
2. someone can tell me how these issues can be "debugged" in general? I believe there must be a way to figure out which part of the code causes trouble
3. it might be related to the fact that `measure` involves functions like `MatrixExp` that automatically use multiple cores and it could lead to some conflicts with all local kernels since each kernel might want to distribute over the cores...

**Update**
It appears to me that this is a problem specific to my Mathematica 10.0.2 on Linux 64bit at work (8cores). I wanted to replicate the behavior at home (Windows 8 64bit, Mathematica 10.0.1, 4 cores) - without success... So I will most likely update this question with code on Monday, when I am at work again.

**Update 2**
I believe that I found out the issue, and I would like to know if you think that makes sense. Actually, as mentioned, none of my functions should cause side-effects. I just noticed, that my Mathematica kernels do not quit reliably. That means, a `Quit[]` sometimes leaves a `WolframKernel` and maybe followers open in `top`. These *left-overs also exist if I completly close Mathematica* via the GUI, so that no Help/notebooks/whatsoever are opened. Obviously, this is not intended and I noticed that after closing all those left-overs there seem to be no side-effects. This somehow seems to solve my issue for this particular case but introduces even more problems because I do not want to investigate all running processes before I use Mathematica and clear manually - in fact, I would have to close everything, investigate `ps -A | grep "WolframKernel\|mathematica\|MathKernel"` and `kill` processes everytime I change some functions to be sure there is no unwanted crosstalk between the actual kernel and some "zombies". I know, probably there should be no connection to those left-over kernels, but apparently I observe no issues if they are killed.

Comment: It is probably impossible to say much of use without having full code needed to replicate the issue.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks! I already thought so and will try to minimize the code as much as possible. After that I will of course post it here

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Please see my latest update. The issue seems to be related to kernels that do not close properly, rather than true side-effects in my code.

Comment: see also: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104328/mysterious-behaviour-of-paralleltable and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104310/export-bug-in-combination-with-paralleltable. I still do not have a solution ...

Comment: Certainly this might be a problem of kernels not closing properly. Regardless, we really need full code to replicate in order to say much.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I fully understand the code request. Yet, so far I haven't been able to reproduce the issue when past kernels are closed properly. Even after 40 evaluations of the same `ParallelTable` results were identical - with non-closed kernels in background I basically got different results after each iteration. Given that possibly nobody will be able to reproduce this, since this kernel issue seems pretty unique, I do not think providing code will help at this stage. If the problems appears again, I will for sure provide the code! Thanks for confirming the possible kernel relation!

Comment: If you do manage to get a replicable example, we really want to see it. Can be sent to our tech support, reference this thread and my remark about it.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I will do my best! Maybe I can figure out when kernels do not close so that I can at least provide this information together with code.